# Comparing table structure and contents using pg_dump output from two different databases

Tags: postgresql

If I have the output of `pg_dump` from two different databases, how can I get the difference in structure and contents of all the tables between these two databases?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way would be to dump the schema as plain sql and use text diff.

Or you can use tool like [apgdiff](https://www.apgdiff.com/) which produces ddl statements representing the difference between the two database schemas.